# RxJava Zip two observables without completing them

Tags: rx-java, rxandroidble

I have two observables: first is from library RxAndroidBle:

```
Observable<RxBleConnection> bluetoothObservable = RxBleClient.create(getBaseContext()).getBleDevice(macAddress)
.establishConnection(false)
```

Which connects to device and keeps connection while it has subscribers, and another

```
Observable<Response> serverObservable = Observable.fromCallable(() -> callServer())
```

Then I zip them together

```
bluetoothObservable.zipWith(serverObservable , (rxBleConnection, s) -> {
                                Log.d(TAG, "zip done");
                                return "mock result";
                            }).subscribe((s) -> {},
                                    Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

But after zip `bluetoothObservable` gets unsubscribed and connection immediately falls. What should I do to zip those observables and keep `bluetoothObservable` alive/subscribed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.zip()` you can use:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  bluetoothObservable, 
  serverObservable,
  (rxBleConnection, s) -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "combined");
    return "mock result";
  }
)
  .subscribe(
    (s) -> {},
    Throwable::printStackTrace
  )
```

Explanation: `zip` tries to combine outputs from both `Observable`s one by one. If one of them will complete and all previous emissions from that `Observable` were matched — there is no point of keeping the subscription to the other `Observable` as the subsequent emissions will not be used. `combineLatest` just tries to combine all emissions from both `Observable`s into pairs that are the *latest*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try and then report

Comment: No, I'm afraid `bluetoothObservable` still gets unsubscribed

Comment: I have just checked the exact same code and it works for me so there are two possible situations: the flow is throwing an exception or your `bluetoothObservable` completes by itself.

Comment: Yes, you're right, an exception is thrown. Thank you for your answer!